# HABTM and has_one model error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two classes: `Restream` and `Channel`. Channel could have many restreams and restream can belong to many channels. However, I need `Restream` also to store `active_channel` -- id of a channel that is using it now.

```
class Restream < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :active_channel, class_name: 'Channel'

  has_and_belongs_to_many :channels
  ...
end

class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :restreams
  ...

end
```

Migration I wrote for add `active_channel`:

```
add_column :restreams, :active_channel, :integer, index: true
add_foreign_key :restreams, :channels, column: :active_channel
```

Still every time I run `rails c` and call `Restream.last` I get this:

```
irb(main):002:0> Restream.last   
  Restream Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "restreams".* FROM "restreams"  ORDER BY "restreams"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column channels.restream_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "channels".* FROM "channels" WHERE "channels"."restr...
                                                   ^
: SELECT  "channels".* FROM "channels" WHERE "channels"."restream_id" = $1  ORDER BY "channels"."name" ASC LIMIT 1
    from /bundler_cache/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:637:in `prepare'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:637:in `prepare_statement'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:596:in `exec_cache'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:585:in `execute_and_clear'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:160:in `exec_query'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:355:in `select'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:32:in `select_all'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:70:in `select_all'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:39:in `find_by_sql'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:639:in `exec_queries'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/association_relation.rb:32:in `exec_queries'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:515:in `load'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:243:in `to_a'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb:42:in `get_records'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb:57:in `find_target'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:138:in `load_target'
... 4 levels...
    from /bundler_cache/gems/awesome_print-1.6.1/lib/awesome_print/ext/active_record.rb:45:in `each'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/awesome_print-1.6.1/lib/awesome_print/ext/active_record.rb:45:in `inject'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/awesome_print-1.6.1/lib/awesome_print/ext/active_record.rb:45:in `awesome_active_record_instance'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/awesome_print-1.6.1/lib/awesome_print/formatter.rb:26:in `format'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/awesome_print-1.6.1/lib/awesome_print/inspector.rb:137:in `unnested'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/awesome_print-1.6.1/lib/awesome_print/inspector.rb:104:in `awesome'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/awesome_print-1.6.1/lib/awesome_print/core_ext/kernel.rb:10:in `ai'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/awesome_print-1.6.1/lib/awesome_print/core_ext/kernel.rb:20:in `ap'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/awesome_print-1.6.1/lib/awesome_print/inspector.rb:31:in `output_value'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I found out, that it fails on statement `SELECT  "channels".* FROM "channels" WHERE "channels"."restream_id" = $1  ORDER BY "channels"."name" ASC LIMIT 1`

What am I doing wrong? Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the column name should be `restream_id` not `restreams`.

And that you added a column and foreign reference to `Restream` for `Channel`, but has one would mean that `Channel` belongs to `Restream`, which is the other way around from your code.

I think you could easily fix this by saying that a `Restream` belongs to a `Channel`.

```
class Restream < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :active_channel, class_name: 'Channel'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :channels
  ...
end

class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :restreams
  ...
end
```

This solution assumes you want to store the "active" channel on the restream, meaning a channel can have many/one restream(s).

If you want the other way around, you will have to switch around all the code, rollback your DB change your migration, then everything should work.

Comment: Yes, changing `has_one` to `belongs_to` solved it. I also think it sounds better with `belongs_to`=) Also I got back to rails guides and realised, what was the problem, but now try to realise why `has_one` creates `id` like this. I would expect it creating id's like `belongs_to` actually does.

Comment: @Ngoral, `belongs_to`, `has_one`, `has_many` and `has_and_belongs_to_many` only control the queries used to fetch records. But the actual column creation within the database is up to the migration that ran. And `has_one` is special, you can make it `has_many` by just changing the code, since it's the `belongs_to` that really matters and holds the foreign relationship. The only difference between `has_many` and `has_one` is that `has_one` does a `SELECT ... LIMIT 1` query that's limited to a single record. But both use the other model's `belongs_to` for the query.

Answer (score 0):

You messed up the column name. In ActiveRecord conventions foreign key columns should end with `_id`.

If you have not yet committed the bad migration you can simply roll it back with `rake db:rollback` and fix the migration.

```
add_column :restreams, :active_channel_id, :integer, index: true
add_foreign_key :restreams, :channels, column: :active_channel_id
```

Otherwise you need to create a new migration that renames the column.

```
remove_foreign_key(:restreams, :channels, column: :active_channel)
remove_index(:restreams, :active_channel_id)
rename_column(:restreams, :active_channel, :active_channel_id)
add_foreign_key(:restreams, :channels, column: :active_channel_id)
add_index(:restreams, :active_channel_id)
```

And you should be using a `belongs_to` and not a `has_one` relationship as the latter puts the foreign key column on the other side of the relationship.

```
class Restream < ActiveRecord::Base
  # stores the relation as `restreams.active_channel_id`
  belongs_to :active_channel, class_name: 'Channel', 
                              optional: true

  has_and_belongs_to_many :channels
  ...
end

class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  # or has_one
  has_many :active_restreams, class_name: 'Restream', 
                              foreign_key: 'active_channel_id'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :restreams
  ...

end
```

Comment: You're right about the column naming. But `has_one :active_channel` will still try to find the channel by querying `"channels"."restream_id"`, which isn't what the migration is doing. Adding a column to restrem means it `belongs_to`.

Comment: Just edited the answer with an explanation that the asker should be using `belongs_to`

Comment: @max Actually now it works without changing a migration, but only by replacing `has_one` with `belongs_to`

Comment: Thats wierd. I would still rename the column for consistency and coherence though.